# Cross compilation for ARM using Bazel custom toolchain

Tags: cross-compiling, bazel

I was struggling hard to cross compile a program for ARM processor using Bazel.  I followed below tutorial from bazel:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain

When I run the exact command written in the above tutorial, the error log is as below:

> manikanta@manikanta-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/my_project/bazel_toolchain_test_data$ bazel build --crosstool_top=//tools/arm_compiler:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a
>   ERROR: no such package 'tools/arm_compiler': BUILD file not found on package path
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 0.724s
>   INFO: 0 processes.
>   FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)

I am clueless as I am new to Bazel. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a simple example (hello-world) on bazel use for cross-compiling for ARM? I work on Linux/Ubuntu machine x86_64 and want to cross-compile for the ARM64 device. I guess I'm in a similar situation as you

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that there's no file called `BUILD` in the `tools/arm_compiler` directory in your workspace (and I'm guessing `tools/arm_compiler` itself doesn't exist).

If you're trying to write your own custom toolchain, which is what the tutorial covers, see the [Writing the BUILD file](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain#writing-the-build-file) section for how to write the BUILD file. Other sections of the tutorial also include instructions on writing the accompanying CROSSTOOL file (which defines compiler properties) and the compiler itself (i.e. the actual file).

If you just want to build with a different CPU, you can simply write `bazel build --cpu=armeabi_v7a` (with the default toolchain). Ahtough I believe in the case of `armeabi-v7a` the default toolchain doesn't work well (vs., say, building Android native code).